# Trying to randomize a news ticker interval in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, intervals, ticker

I have a jQuery-based scrolling news ticker that uses a set interval in milliseconds to control the delay between the reveal of each new section of text.  I'd like to randomize the delay so that it more closely mimics the way a realtime news feed would look.

I've tried experimenting with some Math.random javascript where the `newsTickerInterval` parameter is, but `JS` is not my native language and I'm having trouble making it work.

Here's the jQuery function my scroller uses to config the display:

```
$(function () {         
$(".demo2").bootstrapNews({
        newsPerPage: 4,
        autoplay: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        navigation: false,
        direction: 'down',
        newsTickerInterval: 3000,
        onToDo: function () {
            //console.log(this);
        }
    });       
});
```

Any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `newsTickerInterval`, make a function `getNewsTickerDelay` that generates a random delay interval and call it using a `setTimeout` whenever needed.

```
$(function () {         
    $(".demo2").bootstrapNews({
        newsPerPage: 4,
        autoplay: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        navigation: false,
        direction: 'down',
        getNewsTickerDelay: function() {
            var minimumInterval = 2000;
            var maximumInterval = 5000;
            var additionalInterval = Math.floor(
                Math.random() * (maximumInterval - minimumInterval)
            );

            return minimumInterval + additionalInterval;
        },
        onToDo: function () {
            //console.log(this);
        }
    });       
});
```

So, every time your timeout is called, set another one with a random delay using `getNewsTickerDelay`

--EDIT--

As pointed out by `@Barmar`, you might need to tweak the implementation of the plugin in your case and implement its internal `animate` method to use your defined random interval instead of a fixed value. You'll just need to replace the `self.options.newsTickerInterval` in that plugin's JS to `self.options.getNewsTickerDelay()`. That is if you are willing to mutate the plugin's implementation.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be one of the available options. I assume he's using this plugin: https://github.com/gagi270683/jQuery-bootstrap

Comment: Oh! Didn't realise that.

Comment: That's correct. Sorry I should have been more specific about the source.

Comment: I made two JSFiddles to demonstrate where I'm at.  First is a working example but with the fixed interval:

https://jsfiddle.net/mandrake_slink/gt9o6qkd/4/

Next, the result of the mods suggested by Sajal.  No luck with randomization, and the interval between panels seems to be at zero, so I'm clearly missing something:

https://jsfiddle.net/mandrake_slink/cz9q52dr/2/

Comment: Note:  I just tried both fiddles with Chrome and neither is working.  They do seem to run ok with Firefox.

Comment: @MandrakeSlink Yeah, noticed that. Quite strange!
Tried to work the same with jsBin and it worked just fine (even in chrome).

Here's the link: https://jsbin.com/jawocupare/edit?js,output

P.S. seems that you missed replacing  `self.options.newsTickerInterval` with `self.options.getNewsTickerDelay()` in your shared fiddle, so I fixed that

Comment: Aha, yes it's been a long day... lol.  Thanks So very much!  It's now doing exactly what I was intending.  Sajal Preet Singh is the man!

Comment: @MandrakeSlink, the established way to appreciate an answer is to mark it as accepted. So, it would be nice if you could do so. It'll also help other users to know that the original post has got its desired answer.